# Shared website link doesn't open from facebook mobile application

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

When I share website links (www-nari-news) to my facebook page, it opens nicely if the mobile is connected though wifi but if the connection is 2G/3G/4G and if visitors clicks on a shared link from my facebook page then it shows like below image:
[image]

I'm not sure why it happens. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try with a different provider?

Comment: Yes, tried with different provider and different devices / browsers.